# CSS: Some problems with aligning LABELs inside DIV

Tags: css

I have a `div` to contain labels. When I put labels on it, they get left-aligned. But I need one label to get left-aligned, while the other should be right-aligned. That is one `label` on the left edge of the `div`, and one `label` on the right edge. Is it possible to do?

`Div`'s class is

```
.divclass {
    color: darkblue;
    font-family: serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-color: silver;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

`Label`'s class is

```
.labelclass {
    background: silver;
    color: #191970;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc,
        0 2px 0 #c9c9c9,
        0 3px 0 #bbb,
        0 4px 0 #b9b9b9,
        0 5px 0 #aaa,
        0 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1),
        0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1),
        0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3),
        0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2),
        0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25),
        0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2),
        0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a class to the label you want to align to the right, and then use `float` property on it....

```css
.divclass {
  color: darkblue;
  font-family: serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: silver;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.labelright {
  float: right
}

.labelclass {
  background: silver;
  color: #191970;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #ccc, 0 2px 0 #c9c9c9, 0 3px 0 #bbb, 0 4px 0 #b9b9b9, 0 5px 0 #aaa, 0 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 20px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="divclass">
  <label class="labelclass">test</label>
  <label class="labelclass">test</label>
  <label class="labelclass">test</label>
  <label class="labelclass labelright">test</label>
  <label class="labelclass">test</label>
  <label class="labelclass">test</label>
</div>
```

If you can't alter the HTML, you can use `nth-of-type` selector for the label you want to float.